# how can i skip user from entering his details in Box api

Tags: api, box-api

I wanted to integrate Box cloud into my software.It is desktop application.Where in user can upload or download data from his Box account.
I had went through API docs of Box.

My application has the Box login credentials ie box user id and password.
but when i gone through documentation i found that at step 3( http://developers.box.com/get-started/ ) user has to enter his box credentials, which i don't want as i have it.

So is there any way i can get access to box account using box credentials and not by authorization process?

Plz help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The process I use is to write the token you get from the login webpage to a file, and then retrieve that each time it is needed.  I store it with the user name which is also returned from the site where you pick up the token after the user logs in ('https://www.box.com/api/1.0/rest?action=get_auth_token&api_key= blah blah blah').  The tokens don't seem to expire at all, but you can expire it yourself periodically and make the user login at the website.  You can also authorize the user at the machine level so she doesn't grab somebody else's token, if that's necessary.

Mike

Comment: thanks for your assistance..but still i am facing some issues.can i get your mail id for help plz. Thanks

Comment: Nope, glad to help, but we'll do it here so maybe others can benifit.  Besides, lots of really smart folks hang around here and they will be able to help, too.